# Laravel 4 Blade Templating Engine with Conditional layout

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm using L4 with Blade. I'd like to be able to conditionally extend a layout. For normal use, I'd like to extend the master layout, and for ajax renders, I'd like to be able to extend the ajax template. I use the following code:

```
@if ( isset($ajax) )
    @extends('layouts.ajax')
@else
    @extends('layouts.master')
@endif
```

But when the page renders it just prints out @extend('layouts.master').

Does anyone know how to conditionally extend a layout or another?

Thanks

Comment: because its @extends not extend

Comment: That's now why. That was a typo I made here. Sorry about the confusion. I've edited the question

Comment: I had to plus one the typo in the comment `addressnig` the typo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try on the **first line**:

```
@extends('layouts.' . isset($ajax) ? 'ajax' : 'master')
```

**EDIT**

You also can use it this way:

```
@extends(((Request::ajax()) ? 'layouts.ajax' : 'layouts.master'))
```