# Laravel 4 Ajax check to include XMLHttpRequest (from Magnific Popup)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, magnific-popup

Using [**the code from this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455373/laravel-4-blade-templating-engine-with-conditional-layout),

```
@extends('layouts.' . isset($ajax) ? 'ajax' : 'master')
```

to check for Ajax. It works for regular Ajax page loads but not when using a popup.

In this case I'm using Magnific Popup's Ajax mode, the request header is XMLHttpRequest but Laravel returns the non-ajax (extended) layout.

Answer (score 11):

First of all I don't know how the `$ajax` variable is being set(`isset($ajax)`), but the right way to check for an ajax request in `Laravel` is

```
if(Request::ajax()) {
    // ...
}
```

Or, short form (using [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a) operator in a single expression)

```
$ajax = Request::ajax() ? true : false;
```

So, according to your link of another answer, this should work

```
@extends(((Request::ajax()) ? 'layouts.ajax' : 'layouts.master'))
```

**How this works ?**

In `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http` there is a `Request.php` class you can see

```
/**
 * Determine if the request is the result of an AJAX call.
 * 
 * @return bool
 */
public function ajax()
{
    return $this->isXmlHttpRequest();
}
```

Here `isXmlHttpRequest()` is an extended method from  `Request.php` class of `Symphony`, because `Laravel`'s `Request` class extends `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request.php` and in this class there is the main method which determines the `ajax` request by

```
public function isXmlHttpRequest()
{
    return 'XMLHttpRequest' == $this->headers->get('X-Requested-With');
}
```

So, if `X-Requested-With` request header is set then it's an ajax request and if this header is not sent then it's not an `ajax` request. So, the question is how `isset($ajax)` is being set and if it's set by you then the `jQuery` library you are using it is not doing it but it's sending `X-Requested-With` request header instead and in this case you should use `Laravel`'s `Request::ajax()` method to determine the `ajax` request.

BTW, I would prefer to use a completely different `view` for `ajax` request which doesn't extend `master` layout. You may like this [Detect Ajax Request-Php And Frameworks](http://heera.it/detect-ajax-request-php-frameworks).