# Laravel angularjs Request::ajax() always false

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, coffeescript, laravel-4

I'm building application with angularjs and laravel 4. 
Everything is fine but I need now to allow only XHR requests.

This is what I have at the beginning of my controller.
But this statement is always false.

```
    if (!\Request::ajax())
    {
        return Response::json(array('halt'=>Request::ajax()));
    };
```

In angular I'm using standard $http service.

```
angular.module('APP')
.factory("API", ($http,$q,appClient,apiURL) ->
 class FB
  constructor:->
    this.deferredData = $q.defer();
  info: (reload)->
    $http(
      method: "get"
      url: apiURL+'game/'+appClient+"/info"
    ).success((res)->
      dostuff()
    )
```

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166320/laravel-4-ajax-check-to-include-xmlhttprequest-from-magnific-popup/20167599#20167599).

Comment: Usually there a header set by most browsers when doing an AJAX call: `X-Requested-With: XMLHTTPRequest`. Do you see that header from the browser inspector?

Comment: Thank's a lot I have to set:
`$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When doing AJAX calls, the `X-Requested-With` header is often set to `XMLHttpRequest`.  Laravel's `Request::ajax()` method is built on top of a Symfony2 method that simply checks for the presence of this header.

In October 2012, Angular.js [removed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3a75b1124d062f64093a90b26630938558909e8d) this header because they felt that it was rarely used.

As @Thrustmaster and yourself mentioned in the comments, you need to set:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"
```

Answer (score 23):

If you'd rather not modify the front-end angular application (or can't), and would rather modify your Laravel code to differentiate between Angular JS AJAX requests vs. other requests, you can also use [`Request::wantsJson()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#request-information):

```
if(Request::wantsJson()) {
    // Client wants JSON returned 
} else {
    // Client does not want JSON returned
}
```

The `wantsJson` method relies on the standard `Accepts` HTTP header (rather than the non-standard `X-Requested-With` header) for the presence of `application/json`.  As long as Angular JS leaves that in by default and you don't remove it on purpose, this method should be reliable.

Comment: Adding my 2 cents - this answer will help in some cases but will not help in others e.g when angular loads template files (router, directives, etc) - although technically done via ajax, Laravel `Request::wantsJson()` will not intercept it. The accepted answer by Moshe is IMOH a better way to verify that all requests are handled correctly. Regardless, on Laravel's side you should always check for `if (Request::isAjax() || Request::wantsJson()) {}`.

Answer (score 14):

For AngularJs newbies looking for where to add `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"`

Here is an example:

```
var angularApp = angular
  .module('angularApp', [
    'ngResource',
  ])
  .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
  }]);
```