# How to use Javascript viariables in a php echo (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I'm using Laravel Framwork and try to use a javascript viarable inside a php echo call but it doesn't work. Do you have any solution?

```
function getMachineName (id) {
        return item = {{ Machine:: find(id)->name }};
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript variables can not be used within PHP . you need to use Ajax for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Uhm.. Could you tell me how I can do that? I don't know how to use Ajax for this purpose.

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414632/how-to-use-ajax-function-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

In a straight up way you can't use the variables 
But what you can do is after the function is done you can redirect to the same page and put the variable as a parameter in the URL and access it from there. 
Though as suggested ajax would be better for that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do and the number of `Machines` there are in your database, you could do this in your controller:

```
$machines = Machine::all();
```

And something like this in your view:

```
var machines = {{ $machines }};

function getMachineName (id) {
    for (i = 0; i < machines.length ; i++) {
        if (machines[i].id === id) {
            return machines[i].name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Going to try this now!