# Laravel - check if Ajax request

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to find a way to determine Ajax calls in Laravel but I have not found any documentation about it.

I have an `index()` controller function where I want to handle the response differently based on the nature of the request. Basically this is a resource controller method that is bound to GET request.

```php
public function index()
{
    if(!$this->isLogin())
        return Redirect::to('login');
            
    if(isAjax()) // This is what I am needing.
    {
        return $JSON;
    }

    $data = array(
        'records' => $this->table->fetchAll()
    );

    $this->setLayout(compact('data'));
}
```

I know the other methods of determining the Ajax request in PHP but I want something specific to Laravel.

Thanks

**Updated:**

I tried using

```php
if(Request::ajax())
{
    echo 'Ajax';
}
```

But I am receiving this error:

`Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::ajax() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

The class shows that this is not a static method.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Maybe this helps. You have to refer the @param

```
         /**       
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @param  Illuminate\Http\Request $request
         * @return Response
         */
        public function index(Request $request)
        {
            if($request->ajax()){
                return "AJAX";
            }
            return "HTTP";
        }
```

Comment: You are right. This will work in my case as i am using namespace of `Illuminate\Http\Request;` in my controllers. Thanks

Comment: You can also use "request()->ajax()" if needed

Comment: I can confirm this works in 5.2. I used the helper `request()->ajax()` Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

## $request->wantsJson()

You can try `$request->wantsJson()` if `$request->ajax()` does not work

`$request->ajax()` works if your JavaScript library sets an X-Requested-With HTTP header.

By default Laravel set this header in js/bootstrap.js

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

In my case, I used a different frontend code and I had to put this header manually for `$request->ajax()` to work.

But `$request->wantsJson()` will check the axios query without the need for a header `X-Requested-With`:

```
// Determine if the current request is asking for JSON. This checks Content-Type equals application/json.
$request->wantsJson()
// or 
\Request::wantsJson() // not \Illuminate\Http\Request
```

Comment: Use `$request->wantsJson()` if your controller is deciding whether to respond with JSON or something else. This is a better approach than using `$request->isAjax()` because `wantsJson()` follows the HTTP spec for [Content Negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation).

Answer (score 24):

You are using the wrong `Request` class. If you want to use the Facade like: `Request::ajax()` you have to import this class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

And not `Illumiante\Http\Request`

---

Another solution would be injecting an instance of the real request class:

```
public function index(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()){
        return "AJAX";
    }
```

(Now here you have to import `Illuminate\Http\Request`)

Comment: you are right. I fixed that. Some other guy put a use statement above and i didn't look at that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 23):

To check an ajax request you can use `if (Request::ajax())`

Note: 
If you are using laravel 5, then in the controller replace

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

with

```
use Request;
```

I hope it'll work.

Answer (score 12):

```
if(Request::ajax())
```

Looks to be the right answer.
http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_ajax

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you mean, but Laravel makes use of the Facade design pattern so that your calls can be made like static methods: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades#facade-class-reference That link shows a list of Facades Laravel uses. Are you using it in a Controller?

Comment: i was using wrong use statement. sorry But thanks for an overview of Facades :) This is informative.

Answer (score 8):

For those working with **AngularJS** front-end, it does not use the Ajax header laravel is expecting. ([Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24947865/922522))

Use [Request::wantsJson()](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#request-information) for AngularJS:

```
if(Request::wantsJson()) { 
    // Client wants JSON returned 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Those who prefer to use laravel helpers they can check if a request is ajax using laravel `request()` helper.

```
if(request()->ajax())
   // code
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public function index()
{
    if(!$this->isLogin())
        return Redirect::to('login');

    if(Request::ajax()) // This is check ajax request
    {
      return $JSON;
    }

    $data = array();
    $data['records'] = $this->table->fetchAll();

    $this->setLayout(compact('data'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes `Request::ajax()` doesn't work, then use `\Request::ajax()`

Comment: It will not work if the namespace is not used. Anyways thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Do something like this
public function functionName(User $user): string
{
    (string) $message = "";
    // check if request is ajax
    if(request()->ajax())
    {
        if($this->isOwner($user->id)){
            $message = 'success';
        }else{
            $message = "You are unauthorized to perform this action.";
        }
    }else{
        $message = 'Wrong server request';
    }
    return $message;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after writing the jquery code perform this validation in your route or in controller.

```
$.ajax({
url: "/id/edit",
data:
name:name,
method:'get',
success:function(data){
  console.log(data);}
});

Route::get('/', function(){
if(Request::ajax()){
  return 'it's ajax request';}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Most of the answers are working fine. We can also check the request header

```
request()->header('Accept')=='application/json'
```

to check the request type