# "$request->ajax()" why is not working in laravel middleware?

Tags: ajax, laravel, session, middleware

$request->ajax(); is not working in laravel 5.5 i want to hendel session redirection for ajax

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Closure;
use Session;
//use Request; 

class IsLogin 
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) 
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            return response()->json(['Session_error'=>'Session Expired'], 401);
            //throw new AuthenticationException('Unauthenticated');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that your middleware is being handled at all? Have you registered the middleware in the `Http/Kernel` class?

Comment: @ nakov
'Islogin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsLogin::class, i already registred in kernel also

Comment: you can also use `request()->ajax()` and have you apply this middleware at route

Comment: @ Knuks  if (request()->ajax()) is also not working :(
 have you apply this middleware at route
>> yes.

Comment: please refer may be helps you https://medium.com/@dennissmink/laravel-ajax-only-middleware-f979a9ab20fe

Comment: difference only that `public function handle($request, Closure $next)`

Comment: https://medium.com/@dennissmink/laravel-ajax-only-middleware-f979a9ab20fe
>>Already try but not working

Comment: @Web3 try after remove `Request` in handle function and you can see existing middleware for example

Comment: Hi, hope this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231587/laravel-check-if-ajax-request

Comment: @emjr $request->ajax() is not working. is not able to parse the ajax request so i can't identify ajax request.