# Return json response in ajax request laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-9

I have the following ajax code in my frontend.

```js
var formData = $('#application-information-step-one').serialize();
var actionUrl = $('#application-information-step-one').attr('action');
$.ajax({
      url: actionUrl,
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      success: function(data) {
        var resp = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(resp);
      },
      error: function(data) {

      }
```

And following code to return json response from my controller if the request is `ajax`:

```
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Information saved sucessfully !'
            ],200)->headers('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        }
```

But with the above code setup. Laravel returns HTML code of same page from where the request was made.

HTML page is rendered in preview section of network tab .

Can anyone suggest what am I missing here ?

Comment: the `console.log(resp);` is what you want to "return"?

Comment: I want to show `'message'` from json response

Comment: the literal string 'message'?

Comment: Add `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 0):

Return JSON response from controller

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success', 
        'data' =>[], 
        'message' => 'Information saved successfully!'
    ], 200);
}
```

In AJAX success function code:

```
 success: function (data) {
     console.log(data.message);
 },
```

and add to AJAX request object next parameters too

```
dataType: 'json',
contentType: false,
processData: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for Ajax request is incorrect, otherwise the controller wouldn't have outputted HTML.

You can try several things:

- `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;` at the top of the file
- replace `request->ajax()` with `Request::wantsJson()`
- use `request()->ajax()`

Any of the above subject to your Laravel version.

[More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231587/laravel-check-if-ajax-request)