# laravel 5.1 Request::ajax return false

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Hello i use same script for **Laravel** **4.2** and **Laravel** **5.1** and problem is for **Laravel 4.2 work perfectly**, but on **Laravel 5.1 i can't understand why it's return bad result**

Problem is why I got `$request->ajax()` false for Laravel 5.1?

routes.php

```
Route::post('/upload-image', [
    'as' => 'upload-image-post',
    'uses' => 'PageController@profileImage'
]);
```

PageController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PageController extends Controller
{

    public function profileImage(Request $request) 
    {
        //here is problem
        //result good: (Laravel 4.2 shows true)
        //result bad: (Laravel 5.1 shows false)
        var_dump($request->ajax());
    }

}
```

upload-image.blade.php (js)

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#upload_image').click(function(event) {
        $('#image').trigger('click');
    });

    $('#image').change(function(event) {
        /* Act on the event */
        $('#imageform').submit();
    });

    $('#imageform').ajaxForm({      
        beforeSubmit: function() {  
        },
        success: function(msg) {
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {

        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            if(xhr.status != 401) {
                $('#image').val('');
                result = xhr.responseText;
                result = $.parseJSON(result);

                if( !$.isEmptyObject(result.file_base_url) ) {
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function() {
                        $('#register_profile_photo').attr('src', img.src);
                        $('#register_profile_photo').attr('alt', result.image_alt);
                        //spinner.stop();
                        $('#upload-image-error').text('');  
                    }
                    img.src = result.file_base_url;
                } else {
                    $('#upload-image-error').text(result.image[0]); 
                }

            }   
        }
    });
});
```

upload-image.blade.php (html)

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name='imageform' role="form" id="imageform" method="post" action="{!! route('upload-image-post') !!}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" placeholder="Please choose your image" >
    </div>
</form>

<div class="profile-img">
    <img style="float: right" id="register_profile_photo" src="default.png" alt="Default image">
    <div style="float: right" class="img-edit"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="upload_image">Edit picture</a></div>
</div>
```

PS. If you test for laravel 4.2 this code need change from "{!! .. !!}" to "{{ .. }}"

Comment: try `$request->wantsJson()` instead, it relies on the standard `Accepts` header instead of the non-standard `X-Requested-With` header. This may be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20475460/697370)

Comment: Are other parts of your controller working?

Comment: others methods is simple methods not ajax

Comment: @watcher i think u don't understand problem.. i got not ajax request, after press image edit, i got redirect in route, but not ajax request..

Comment: @J.Kol, try watcher's method. He is correct and he already understood the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this problem is caused by Laravel version. Laravel sources show, that `ajax()` call is propagated to [Symfony's request component](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blame/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php). And that source changed good 5 years back.

You should trace if `X-Requested-With` header is sent to your application in both cases. You can also set breakpoint to `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::isXmlHttpRequest()` and see what you have in headers.