# Laravel 4 - How to render child view which @extends('parent'), without the parent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Well, the title might be a bit confusing, so let me put some light on the situation.
I have a base template in Blade containing basic html and navigation, which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pl">
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">

                @section('title')
                    <title>Page Title</title>
                @show
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <header id="logo"></header>

        <nav id="mainmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="page1">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="page3">Page 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="page4">Page 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And then a bunch of child views for each page, which go like this:

```
@extends('layouts.base')

@section('title')
    <title>Page 1</title>
@stop

@section('content')

<section class="container clearfix">

    <h2 class="section-title">Page 1</h2>
    <div class="content">
              some content here
    </div>
</section>

@stop
```

Now, what I want is being able to conditionally ignore the @extends(), so that I can return a view which is just the child view, that is everything within section of class "container", for being able to stack it up into one-page layout or load using AJAX.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a file at app/views/layouts/base.blade.php ?

Comment: Yes, it's the code on top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
@extends(((condition) ? 'layouts.plain' : 'layouts.base'))
```

Now create a layout named `plain` and keep nothing inside it but just content, this way you can use a plain layout, for example, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20167599/741747).

```
//layouts/plain.blade.php
@yield('content')
```

Comment: That's a nice way to do it. +1

Comment: This is some way, but it means that if there were any changes in the content, I'd have to edit them in two places. I'd really like being able to have more DRY approach.

Comment: No, you don't have to change in two places, why should you think that ?

Comment: @Nicolas, did you check the example another answer link, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20167599/741747) ? This way you can just imply load the view without checking in the controller and view'll be generated on the condition.

Comment: @Nicolas.. the only "second place" would be the new layout, which wouldn't have to change.  It's just that this layout only pulls the `content` section of your view

Comment: Ok, I must have misunderstood something there.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

1. pass the layout to the View as a variable (`$layout`), rather than defining a string in the view.
2. create a second layout with only the `content` section defined.
3. then you can call the `View::make()` from anywhere with the template set according to your needs.

Change the `@extends` in the child view:

```
@extends((isset($layout)) ? $layout : 'layouts.base')
```

create your new "content only" layout: /app/views/layouts/content-only.blade.php:

```
// only this line in the file:
@yield('content')
```

then in normal use:

```
return View::make('child-view');
```

and when you want the content-only version:

```
return View::make('child-view')->with('layout', 'layouts.content-layout');
```

**EDIT** - updated to take into account the tip in Sheikh Heera's answer!